# Exclude certain products based on date range

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

For example, I have sales data for 1 year, and some of the products not available on a specific date range.

I currently have for 1 date range, but what is the best practice if have multiple exclusions?

```
SELECT * FROM XXX
WHERE 
IF(Date BETWEEN '2018-11-22' AND '2019-03-28',
ID IN (8467,8468,8469,8470),
ID IN (8467,8468,8469,8470,9551,9552,9553)
)
```

Especially how to solve the issue if dates are overlapping?

Comment: How do you want multiple exclusions to work?  You need to explain what happens.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I some vision but not a complete picture, for example, I have 10 date ranges with different products to exclude some of them could overlap each other... Basically, if we take a sales range 1 year, I would like to filter out specific products by specific date range...and have the ability to continuously add them new business rules

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to *exclude* values, I am thinking:

```
SELECT *
FROM XXX
WHERE ID IN (8467, 8468, 8469, 8470, 9551, 9552, 9553) AND
      (Date BETWEEN '2018-11-22' AND '2019-03-28' AND
ID NOT IN (9551, 9552, 9553) OR
       Date NOT BETWEEN '2018-11-22' AND '2019-03-28'
      );
```

You can add multiple pairs for other dates.

For a full solution, you might want to create a table with olumns such as:

- `product_id`
- `start_exclusion_date`
- `end_exclusion_date`

And then phrase the query as:

```
select xxx.*
from xxx left join
     exclusions e
     on xxx.id = e.product_id and
        xxx.date >= e.start_exclusion_date and
        xxx.date <= e.end_exclusion_date
where xxx.id in ( . . . );
```

This is likely to be easier to maintain in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select * from xxx
where not(date between '2018-11-22' and '2019-03-28' and id in(9551,9552,9553))
order by id, date
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example for BigQuery Standard SQL and shows direction for building "complete picture" with whitelist and blacklist rules (all with quite simplified dummy data just to demonstrate it in action)

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.xxx` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, DATE '2018-11-22' `date` UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2018-11-23' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '2018-11-24' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, '2018-11-25' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2018-11-26' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2018-11-27' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '2018-11-28' UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, '2018-11-29'
), `project.dataset.whitelist` AS (
  SELECT DATE '2018-11-22' start, DATE '2018-11-29' finish, [2,3] ids UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-11-22', '2018-11-22', [1]
), `project.dataset.blacklist` AS (
  SELECT DATE '2018-11-26' start, DATE '2018-11-28' finish, [1,3] ids UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-11-22', '2018-11-22', [10]
)
SELECT DISTINCT t.*
FROM `project.dataset.xxx` t
JOIN `project.dataset.whitelist` w
  ON (`date` BETWEEN w.start AND w.finish AND id IN UNNEST(w.ids))
JOIN `project.dataset.blacklist` b
  ON NOT(`date` BETWEEN b.start AND b.finish AND id IN UNNEST(b.ids))
```

with result

```
Row id  date     
1   1   2018-11-22   
2   2   2018-11-27   
3   2   2018-11-23   
4   3   2018-11-28   
5   3   2018-11-24
```

Obviously, in real case all involved tables are real tables and query will look just like below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT t.*
FROM `project.dataset.xxx` t
JOIN `project.dataset.whitelist` w
  ON (`date` BETWEEN w.start AND w.finish AND id IN UNNEST(w.ids))
JOIN `project.dataset.blacklist` b
  ON NOT(`date` BETWEEN b.start AND b.finish AND id IN UNNEST(b.ids))
```